# Laravel eloquent: Multiply two columns of two different tables and display

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Carts table columns :

```
    'id',
    'user_id',
    'sp_id',
    'service_id',
    'dryclean',
    'q_Shirt',
    'q_Pant',
    'q_Tie'
```

Pricing table column :

```
'id'
'sp_id'
'Shirt'
'Pant'
'Tie'
```

Both table **do not** have any relationship defined.

In cart controller

```
public function cart($sp_id, $service_id)
    {
     $prices = DB::table('pricings')->where('pricings.sp_id', '=', $sp_id)->get();
     $cart = DB::table('carts')->where('carts.service_id', '=' , $service_id)->where('carts.sp_id','=', $sp_id)->where('user_id', '=' , auth()->id())->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(1)->get();
     return view('user.cart')->with('prices', $prices)->with('cart', $cart);
    }
```

How do I calculate total amount of order?

If column dryclean has value of none then total is **0**.
else total will be

```
(
carts->q_Shirt*prices->Shirt +
carts->q_Pant*prices->Pant +
carts->q_Tie*prices->Tie
)
```

This code is just for understanding of how I am calculating total

Please help me write code in laravel controller to calculate total and how to display it in view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think to understand you well, but you can try this to have some idea.

```
$prices = DB::table('pricings')
                 ->where('pricings.sp_id', '=', $sp_id)
                 ->get();
$cart = DB::table('carts')
          ->where('carts.service_id', '=' , $service_id)
          ->where('carts.sp_id','=', $sp_id)
          ->where('user_id', '=' , auth()->id())
          ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(1)
          ->get();
$total = 0;
$prices->reduce(function($acc, $current) use ($cart, &$total) {
      return $total += ($current->Shirt + $cart->q_Shirt) + 
                ($current->Pant + $cart->q_Pant) + 
                ($current->Tie + $cart->q_Tie);
});
```